# For what real values of $c$ does $x-\ln {(1+e^x)}=c$ hold for some $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For what real values of $c$ does $x-\ln {(1+e^x)}=c$ hold for some $x$?

Rewriting the equation as $\ln {e^x}-\ln {(1+e^x)}=c$, I get $e^c=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$.
Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do... Please rewrite your question. Is $x$ known or not? What do you mean "does it hold"? I mean, for each $x$, you can fix a value of $c$ for which the equation obviously holds...

Comment: $x$ is a real number and so is $c$. No more info is given.

Comment: Well, if no more info is given, then the answer is "This question is unclear and thus cannot be answered".

Comment: it probably means he has to determine the image of that function. It is a valid question, in that case.

Comment: @Emisor How do you know that?

Comment: @5xum Actually the equation holds for all $c<0$ as given in my book and that's what I am trying to prove.

Comment: @StubbornAtom No, that's not true. What **is** true is that *for every $c<0$, there **exists** some value of $x$ such that the equation holds*. But that's **not** the same.

Comment: @5xum That's what I understood from the question given but I will be glad if you can give a hint on how to do it.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Please edit your question to make it clear what you are asking, because what **you** understood from the question is not the same as what you wrote.

Comment: @5xum I wrote it exactly as it was written on an authentic book. Assuming the question has an answer in the form given, I would say that you have to understand it from the perspective you pointed out.

Comment: @StubbornAtom As the question is written, it was put on hold as "unclear what you are asking". This means that at least $5$ other experienced users of this site agree that it the question needs more context to be written around it. This is because sure, in the book, the question has **implicit** context in the form of what chapter the question it appears in, and the questions *around* it, that make the perspective clear. You then took the question *out of the context of the book*, so it is *your* job to provide the context.

Comment: @5xum So its not possible for me to get the question 'out of hold'?

Comment: @StubbornAtom  It is. Users will vote to reopen your question as soon as you fix the problems it has. As I already explained, it lacks context, and because of this, it is not clear what you are asking. If you *fix* that, and make it clear that you are asking for the range of a function (or word it in some other way, but make it clear), I will gladly remove my close vote. But as the question stands now, it is uclear (and no, comments *do not* count. The question must be self-contained, and a user must get all relevant info from the question, not comments.)

Comment: @5xum I did edit it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41086/discussion-between-5xum-and-stubbornatom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Hint**:
>   $$
> e^c = \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \iff e^x = \frac{e^c}{1 - e^c}.
> $$

As $e^x > 0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we get that
$$
\frac{e^c}{1 - e^c} > 0 \iff 1 - e^c > 0 \iff e^c < 1 \iff c<0.
$$